# Can't connect to server through SSH in Django application

Tags: python, django, paramiko

I'm writing fairly simple application which connects to server through SSH (using `paramiko`), does something and writes output to web page. I wrote a script which works well when I run it from command line. However, if I run it in Django application, it can't get through `connect` part.

SSH connect part:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

# application cannot get through this line
transport.connect(username = '***', password = '***')

output = ...
```

View:

```
def ssh_output(request):
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Any idea why does it behave like this? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Is that your complete view function, because 'output' isn't defined in there. Where does your ssh connection get run? I think we need some more code and any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing your Django app may be running under a different user than the user you're running your command line script under.  Also, I'm guessing it might be the first time the Django app user is trying to ssh to the host, so it may be hanging on some sort of 'is it OK to update ~/.ssh/known_hosts' question.

It looks like if you use SSHClient instead of Transport, then you can set the missing host key policy to automatically add the missing host keys ala

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(your_host, port=your_port, username=your_username, password=your_password)
```